# How to store very very large data more than varchar(max) in a SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save json data in SQL Server 2012. Size of that data exceeds the `varchar(max)` size and hence SQL Server truncates the remaining text. What is the solution to store more data?

Comment: If you are exceeding the length of varchar max you have something horribly wrong in your code. The varchar(max) will hold 2GB of text. I understand it is json data but that is a massive amount of information.

Comment: Yes I know we are exceeding length and that is not good practice but here we are processing large excel file data and converting it to json after some calculation. We want to save that data in db so after user confirms everything is good after calculation we can use stored data to quickly save it to improve performance.

Comment: Excel data that is exceeding 2GB? Your performance must be a real challenge on a regular basis.

Comment: What is the purpose of storing > 2GB of JSON formatted data in a database?  Write it to disk and store a reference to the file path.

Comment: @SeanLange & Aaron Hudon, size of excel is hardly 1.6MB but somehow when we insert same data in SQL Server it is getting truncated. So I am really not sure what is happening but seems SQL Server takes 3 bytes for single character. My Json's character count is more than 1500000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql Server has a [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) feature that allows you to store data that doesn't fit in a standard `varchar(max)` field. There is also another option (that uses `FILESTREAM` under the covers) called [FileTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx) that allow you to store a file on the file system but access it directly from T-SQL. It is rather slick but my colleagues and I found the learning curve to be quite steep; lots of little quirks you have to get used to.

Comment: FileTables is available from version 2016 and as mentioned we are using 2012. So FileTables won't be helpful.

Comment: @Parag Patil No, they aren't. We are on 2012 as well... I simply linked the latest docs. *sigh*

Comment: Know what is helpful @ParagPatil , this answer 